# Calling JPA Callbacks from inherited Entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a class SubscriptionProduct extending AbstractProduct.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AbstractProduct")
@EntityListeners(Auditable.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class AbstractProduct  implements Serializable{
  int code;

}

@Entity
@EntityListeners(Auditable.class)
@Table(name="SubscriptionProduct")
public class SubscriptionProduct extends AbstractProduct {
  String description    
}
```

I want to create a log entry whenever an entity is created.
I wrote an EntityListenerclass called Auditable.class

```
public class Auditable {


    @PostPersist
    public void createLogAfterSave(Object O) {

        Session session = createLocalSession();     
        ActivityLog log = new ActivityLog();            
        log.setTablename(O.getClass().getAnnotation(Table.class).name());
        log.setNewValue(O.toString());
        log.setOperation("Create");         
        log.setOldValue(" ");       
        session.save(log);
    }
}
```

Now even though i am expecting two rows one for subscriptionproduct and one for abstractproduct.Two times createLogAfterSave is getting called with SubscriptionProduct.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your annotation is put on the AbstractProduct, you are saving an instance of the concrete class.

The code `O.getClass()` returns the concrete type of the object, no matter where the annotation is located. You are then obtraining a reference to the `SubscriptionProduct` twice. This explains the behaviour you are encountering.

You can avoid getting the listener executed twice by removing one of the annotations. And you can insert two entities (one for the subclass, one for the abstract) by checking manually if the object `O` has a parent class having a `Table` (or `Entity`) annotation using reflection, and creating multiple log accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Through reflection i can find the parent class tablenames but how can i find the values of the fields that are in the parent class.For each entry for a table i want to save to log values in that table.